# scala abstract type parameterized by `this.type`

Tags: scala, types

Im trying to create `Script` and `ScriptType` classes. `ScriptType`s would produce `Script`s of a particular abstract type. `Script`s would be parameterized by the `ScritpType` that created them.

My first attempt looked like this:

```
trait Script[Type <: ScriptType]

sealed trait ScriptType {
  type S <: Script[this.type]
}

object ScriptType {
  class Scala extends ScriptType {
    type S = ScalaScript
  }
}

import ScriptType._

case class ScalaScript(source: String) extends Script[Scala]
```

but im getting a error in compilation regarding the assigning of `type S` in `ScriptType.Scala`

```
Error:(10, 10) overriding type S in trait ScriptType with bounds <: Script[Scala.this.type];
  type S has incompatible type
  type S = ScalaScript
```

in this example is `ScalaScript` not a `Script[Scala.this.type]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScalaScript` is not a `Script[Scala.this.type]`, since `this.type` means a singleton type that's unique for each `Scala` instance.

You can solve this by making `Script` contravariant:

`trait Script[-Type <: ScriptType]`

so that `ScalaScript` can be accepted as a **subtype** of `Script[Scala.this.type]`, since `Scala` is a **supertype** of `Scala.this.type` (the singleton type of any instance of `Scala`).